# How should I refer to myself (single author) when addressing reviewers comments?

Tags: peer-review

I'm referring to the detailed answer to each of their comments. For example, under each comment, which of the following is appropriate: "The author believes that...", or "We believe that...", or "I believe that..."?

Comment: "I" is perfectly fine.

Comment: Is the reviewing process double blind (i.e. do the reviewers know there is a single author)?

Comment: Good point. I don't know that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's up to you and it doesn't matter much. Even if the process is double blind, it does no harm for the reviewers to know there is a single author or, conversely, to think there are multiple authors if you use "we". However if you don't consider yourself a "we", use the singular I. Exclusion of "I" in academic writing is absurd in all circumstances and while this isn't a place for that particular trench war, the comments letter is directly from you to them and "I" is appropriate in such cases.